# How to dynamically call nested functions in C?

Tags: c, function, dynamic, function-pointers

I am actually stuck with the idea as mentioned in the question, about calling nested functions dynamically.

Say I have 4 functions: fun1(), fun2(), fun3(), fun4()

And I want them to be called in this way

```
fun1()
{
  fun2()
  {
    fun3()
    {
      fun4()
      {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how that can be done in C.

Is there a way to do that in C, like using function pointer?

Comment: Yes, function pointers can certainly used for that - have function pointers for `fun2`, `fun3` and `fun4` and then set those accordingly as needed.

Comment: What you show looks like nested function definitions.  It's not clear where you call each of the functions.  Nested functions aren't a part of standard C — languages in the Algol family such as Pascal support nested functions, but C is not in the same family.  GCC supports nested functions to some extent; `clang` likely supports them for compatibility with GCC.  I wouldn't use nested functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As the question very clearly states I currently have no implementation and I am looking forward for some help on this. I did know before posting that C doesn't support nested function. But I was thinking of attaining this via recursion and function pointers

Comment: Thanks @kaylum for your response.

Comment: It is unclear what your goal is. What do you mean by *nested functions* and by *dynamically call*. *nested function* typically describes a function defined inside the scope of another function, with access to variables of its surrounding scope, which is not supported in Standard C. *dynamically call* is redundant as it is understood as call at runtime which is the only type of call available in C.

Comment: You need to read about [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))s and [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))s and a book like [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the documentation of your C compiler (e.g [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `fun1` to call `fun2`, then `fun2` to call `fun3`, and finally `fun3` to call `fun4`, but you want to be able to specify that dynamically - **In other words**, you want to be able to change up the order so that, say, `fun1` calls `fun3`, which calls `fun2`, which calls `fun4`.  And I'm assuming you want to be able to vary the depth of the nesting.

Somehow you have to communicate to each function what the next function is to call.  At first blush we may think the best way to do that is with a callback - i.e., call `fun1` as

```
fun1( fun2 );
```

which tells `fun1` to execute `fun2`, like so:

```
void fun1( void (*f2)( void ) )
{
  f2();
}
```

But how would we tell `fun2` to execute `fun3`?  How would we pass that information through `fun1`?  We could extend the prototype as

```
void fun1( void (*f2)( void (*)(void) ), void (*f3)( void ) )
{
  f2( f3 );
}
```

and call it as

```
fun1( fun2, fun3 );
```

but this isn't very *dynamic* - we'd have to extend the prototype of `fun1` to account for `fun3` calling `fun4`.  And we'd be assuming that we'd *always* be calling a sequence of 3 additional functions.

So, one thought - instead of passing a pointer to a function, we pass an *array* of pointers, terminated with a `NULL`, and each time we call the pointed-to child, we pass the address of the next element in the array:

```
void (*farr[])( void * ) = { fun2, fun3, fun4, NULL }; 

void fun1( void *f )
{
  /**
   * do fun1 stuff here
   */
  void (**flist)( void * ) = f;
  if ( flist[0] )
    flist[0]( flist + 1 ); 
}
```

Here's a proof-of-concept (I used a macro to define the function bodies since they all do exactly the same thing, the only difference is the name):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FUN(N)                           \
void fun##N( void *f, size_t n )         \
{                                        \
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )       \
    printf( "  " );                      \
  puts( "in fun" #N );                   \
  void (**farr)( void *, size_t ) = f;   \
  if ( farr[0] )                         \
  {                                      \
    farr[0]( farr + 1, n+1 );            \
  }                                      \
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )       \
    printf( "  " );                      \
  puts( "returning from fun" #N );       \
}

FUN(1)
FUN(2)
FUN(3)
FUN(4)

int main( void )
{
  void (*farr[])( void *, size_t ) = { fun2, fun3, fun4, fun1, fun3, fun2, NULL };

  puts( "in main" );
  fun1( farr, 0 );

  return 0;
}
```

The function argument type is `void *`, otherwise we get into an infinite nesting thing - `void (**)( void (**)( void (**)( ...`.  Here's the output:

```
in main
in fun1
  in fun2
    in fun3
      in fun4
        in fun1
          in fun3
            in fun2
            returning from fun2
          returning from fun3
        returning from fun1
      returning from fun4
    returning from fun3
  returning from fun2
returning from fun1
```

You could use a different data structure like a list, which would avoid the infinitely nested prototype, but introduces complexity of its own.

So, using that array, you can control the depth and order of the function calls.

Again, this is just one idea, and the code is just a proof of concept - I'm sure there are better ways of doing this, that's just what popped into my head immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Nested functions are not part of the C Standard. Some compilers support them but using them makes the code less portable. Avoid such extensions.

Comment: Hi, at the moment the purpose of my code is to have some kind of nested calls. Since the code is intended to run only on my machine for some results. I don't think portability should not be an issue here. Thanks for your response